# get attribute value of a component tag

Tags: java, attributes, tags, wicket

In wicket I need to get the value of a component's markup tag, for example:

```
<a href="#" name="#">...</a>
```

Here, I need the value of `name` attribute in Wicket java class, for example:

```
String name = /*{link's tag name}*/;
```

I need to assign the `name`'s value as the `name` attribute of the tag `<a>`.

Answer (score 4):

As I realized from your question, you need to get/set tag parameters of your wicket components dinamically.

So, you have several options to do this:

1. Use `AttributeModifier` static methods like `#append("class", "appendedClass")` or `#replace("name", "#")` (*where first param is a tag's attribute, and second is it's value*) to set any value you want to tags, but note that you can't get current values of tag with this approach. Also, pay attention not to add this modifiers in "render" methods (such as `#onConfigure()`), not to create modifiers duplicates in every page's or component's refresh in browser.
2. Override `#onComponentTag()` method like this.

```
    ...new Link ( "link" ) {
        @Override
        protected void onComponentTag ( final ComponentTag tag )
        {
            super.onComponentTag ( tag ); // you should always call super.

            tag.getName (); // get name of the tag: a/div/span..
            tag.setName ( "span" ); // set tag's name.
            tag.getAttribute ( "name" ); // get 'name' attribute's value.
            tag.put ( "name", "#" ); // set 'name' attribute's value
        }
    }
```

3. Use same approach as above, but trhough the `Behavior`'s `onComponentTag` method not to override component's one.

Read [this](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/How+to+modify+an+attribute+on+a+HTML+tag) for some more information, but note that this is fairly old article and something can differ for newer Wicket versions. (for example there is already no need to use `AttributeAppender`, as it moved to AttributeModifier class methods ).

Also, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521416/set-html-element-attribute-from-wicket-message) or [this](http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/how-to-dynamic-add-attribute-to-a-html-tag-in-wicket/) examples. There are many of them in google.